# Customize the From Address field value on Send Email Page Layout

Tags: apex, visualforce

-In salesforce when click on "Send an Email" button under Activity History of Contact by default the User email address is coming as the "From Address" on Send Email page layout. But I want it to be customized based on the Contact's Account.
So how can I do that?

Thanks